# Update p:datatable and retain the rowexpansion status

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have datatable with rowexpansion that have another datatable inside it.
The structure like below:

```
 <p:dataTable id="machine-table" value=#{machinePage.machines} var="machine" styleClass="machine-table">          
  <p:column style="width:16px">
    <p:rowToggler  rendered="#{machine.projectsInMachine.size() > 0}" />
  </p:column> 
  some other machine column here...
  <p:rowExpansion >
    <p:dataTable value="#{machine.projectsInMachine}" var="project" styleClass="project-subtable"  >        
        some project column here
    </p:dataTable>
  </p:rowExpansion>
```

Then I have a pull that will retrieve the machines and the projects data every couple minute, Is there any way that I can update it and retain the current expansion status? Because currently it will always close all the expansion (I update the entire table using poll below).

```
<p:poll widgetVar="machinesPoll"
        interval="60" listener="#{machinePage.prepare()}"
        async="true" global="false"
        autoStart="true" process="@this"
        update="machine-table" partialSubmit="true"
        ignoreAutoUpdate="true" />
```

I can't find any reference regarding the expansion status that I can save in bean. I use: primefaces 6.0 , JSF 2.2.13

Comment: Have you tried using the `rowStatePreserved` attribute of `p:dataTable` component?

Comment: I'm looking for the same functionality, rowStatePreserved does not work in this case. Tested with PF 6.0.17

Comment: Same problem here, rowStatePreserved did not work, Primefaces 6.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep primefaces rowexpansion open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612612/how-to-keep-primefaces-rowexpansion-open)