# Update from an external dialog a row child dataTable inside a rowExpansion Primefaces without closing it

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Once I save from an external dialog, I am trying to update a row from a `rowExpansion` without updating the entire form to dont closes.
I just want to update the child row that I just edited from the `dataTable` of the rowExpansion.

The `idCommandButtonDetailProductChild` button calls the `idDialogDetailProduct` dialog where be edits the data. And in this dialog when saving with the `idCommandButtonUpdate` button I want the row of the `idTableDetailProductChild` to be updated without the `rowExpansion` closing.

My code is the following:

**ProductsList.xhtml** (dataTable with rowExpansion)

```
        <!-- PRODUCT LIST -->
        <p:dataTable id="idTableDetailProduct"                      
                     paginator="false" 
                     value="#{productController.productDetailDTOs}"
                     var="productDetail"
                     selection="#{productController.selectedProductDTOs}"
                     rowKey="#{productDetail.id}"
                     emptyMessage="#{diccBean.msg['product.productNotFound']]}"
                     scrollable="true"
                     scrollHeight="600">                     
                     ...
                                                                    
                <p:rowExpansion>
             
                <!-- PRODUCT LIST CHILD -->
                <p:dataTable id="idTableDetailProductChild" 
                            paginator="false" 
                            value="#{productDetail.productDTO.listProductsChild}"
                            var="productChild"
                            rowKey="#{productDetail.id}"                                     
                            emptyMessage="#{diccBean.msg['product.productChildNotFound']}"
                            scrollable="true">  
                            
                            
                            <!-- VIEW PRODUCT DETAIL  -->
                            <p:commandButton 
                                id="idCommandButtonDetailProductChild" 
                                title="#{diccBean.msg['product.detailProduct']}"
                                icon="fa fa-fw fa-search"
                                action="#{productController.initDetailProduct}"
                                oncomplete="PF('widgetVarDetailProduct').show();"
                                update="tabViewDetalle:idDialogDetailProduct">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{productChild.productDetailDTO.id}" target="#{productController.productDetailId}"/>                                                                
                            </p:commandButton>
```

**ProductDialog.xhtml** (from where I update a child row of the rowExpansion)

```
<h:body>
        <ui:composition>    
            <p:dialog id="idDialogDetailProduct"            
                header="#{diccBean.msg['product.tittleDetailProduct']]}"
                resizable="false" 
                widgetVar="widgetVarDetailProduct" 
                modal="true"
                width="1200"            
                appendTo="@(body)"
                binding="#{productController.idDialogDetailProduct}">
                
                <h:form id="formDetailProduct">
                
                ...

                        <!-- SAVE COMPONENT BUTTON  -->
                        <p:commandButton 
                            id="idCommandButtonUpdate"                         
                            value="Componente: #{diccBean.msg['actions.save']}"
                            action="#{productController.actionUpdate}"
                            process="@form"
                            icon="fa fa-fw fa-check" 
                            update="tabViewDetalle:idTableDetailProduct" /> 


                </h:form>                           
            </p:dialog>         
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update only one row of the rowExpansion (child dataTable) without closing it by putting the index of the parent row in the update attribute.

For example as follows if the parent row were item 3:

```
update=":tabViewDetail:idTableDetailProduct:3:idTableDetailProductChild"
```

And to do it dynamically we could do it by passing it the index of the parent element:

```
update=":tabViewDetail:idTableDetailProduct:#{productController.indexParent}:idTableDetailProductChild"
```

And the index of the parent row can be obtained with the following attribute by add it in the parent dataTable:

```
rowIndexVar="indexParent"
```

And we seted it to the bean like this:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{indexParent}" target="#{productController.indexParent}" />
```

Then the solution would be the following:

**ProductsList.xhtml**

```
            <!-- PRODUCT LIST -->
            <p:dataTable id="idTableDetailProduct"  
                         value="#{productController.productDetailDTOs}"
                         var="productDetail"            
                         ...
                         rowIndexVar="indexParent">
 
 
                <p:rowExpansion>
                 
                    <!-- PRODUCT LIST CHILD -->
                    <p:dataTable id="idTableDetailProductChild"                                 
                                value="#{productDetail.productDTO.listProductsChild}"
                                var="productChild"  
                                ...>                                
                                
                                <!-- VIEW PRODUCT DETAIL  -->
                                <p:commandButton 
                                    id="idCommandButtonDetailProductChild"
                                    ...>                                    
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{indexParent}" target="#{productController.indexParent}" />                                                                            
                                </p:commandButton>
```

**productController Bean (Java)**

```
@ManagedBean(name="productController")      
        public class ProductController{
        
            int indexParent;
        
            public int getIndexParent() {
                return indexParent;
            }

            public void setIndexParent(int indexParent) {
                this.indexParent = indexParent;
            }
 
        }
```

**ProductDialog.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>    
        <p:dialog id="idDialogDetailProduct"            
                ...>                            

            <!-- SAVE COMPONENT BUTTON  -->
            <p:commandButton 
                id="idCommandButtonUpdate"                         
                ... 
                update=":tabViewDetail:idTableDetailProduct:#{productController.indexParent}:idTableDetailProductChild" />  
                                
        </p:dialog>         
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```