# oncomplete with commandButton isn't working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a nested datatable that has an Edit command button, that shows a dialog modal,

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" oncomplete="PF('editStudy').show()" type="button">
                <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{queryStudiesBean.setRenderDialog(true)}" update="editDialogStudy" />
                <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{queryStudiesBean.setEditableStudyIndex(studyIndex)}" update="editDialogStudy: />
                <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{queryStudiesBean.setEditablePatientIndex(patientIndex)}" update="editDialogStudy" />
</p:commandButton>
```

I was fixing the issue of keeping the rows of the child datatable expanded after updating, I was following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68283451/10886220) , but I faced another problem that once I load the datatable page, even before I click on the Edit button, the dialog commandButton that has the update attribute gets evaluated,

```
<p:commandButton process="@form" update="@form,:form2:patient-dt:#{queryStudiesBean.editablePatientIndex}:study-dt" action="#{queryStudiesBean.updateStudy()}" oncomplete="PF('editStudy').hide()" value="Save" styleClass="fixed-button-size" />
```

, this gives null error as `patientIndex` is still null, as I didn't even click on the edit button of the datatable to set the `patientIndex`.

So I managed to solve this by adding `rendered="#{queryStudiesBean.renderDialog}"` attribute to the dialog.

Now I have difficulties setting this boolean to true in the edit button action, the dialog doesn't shows right now, in the above code, I used oncomplete, and set the boolean value in <p:ajax> (as both `action` attribute, and `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` doesn't work for me, I was thinking that the boolean will be set to true before the oncomplete gets called, so the dialog shows, but this is not happend, can someone explains to me why? I saw alots of posts but no one worked for me.

[full datatable code](https://justpaste.it/918z0)

[full dialog code](https://justpaste.it/3sqtu)

I'm using:
primefaces 6.2,
java8

Comment: Can't find `parentIndex`.  If your `update="@form,:form2:patient-dt:#{queryStudiesBean.editablePatientIndex}:study-dt` references parentIndex, it will already been called when the button is rendered.
1. Your `update="editDialogStudy"` needs to be `update=":editDialogStudy"` because it's inside a row of a datatable.
2. You update the form, but the `rendered` is outside the form, so it won't be updated. Put a `<h:panelGroup` around the dialog and update the panelGroup

Comment: Thank you, it worked, yes parentIndex was meant as editablePatientIndex, I edit my question and renamed it, put your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `update="@form,:form2:patient-dt:#{queryStudiesBean.editablePatientIndex}:study-dt` references parentIndex, it will already been called when the button is rendered.

1. Your `update="editDialogStudy"` needs to be `update=":editDialogStudy"` because it's
   inside a row of a datatable.
2. You update the form, but the rendered is outside the form, so it
   won't be updated. Put a `<h:panelGroup...` around the dialog and update
   the panelGroup